# In Bokeh 0.5.0, cannot specify size of chart, and previous versions appear in same output file

Tags: python, bokeh

The "previous versions" problem is the same one stated in [Updated Bokeh to 0.5.0, now plots all previous versions of graph in one window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739390/updated-bokeh-to-0-5-0-now-plots-all-previous-versions-of-graph-in-one-window). I'm running this in iPython notebook; every time I rerun the cell the output html file shows all previous versions, plus the new one.

The other problem is that I can't specify the size and/or aspect ratio of the plot in the output file.

Here is the entire script:

```
x = [0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5]
y = [0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9]
import bokeh.plotting as bplt
bplt.output_file('output.html')
bplt.figure(tools="wheel_zoom", width=1000, height=3000)
bplt.hold()
bplt.circle(x, y, color='red', 
       line_color='black', fill_alpha = 0.8, size = 10,
       title = 'Ternary plot', background_fill='#dddddd')
bplt.line(x=[0,0.5],y=[1,0.134])
bplt.line(x=[0.5,1],y=[0.134,1])
bplt.line(x=[1,0],y=[1,1])
bplt.show()
```

Whatever values I put for width and height, the output is always the same size and aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width` and `height` had to be removed as options to set the plot's width and height from the glyph functions (like `circle`, etc) because some glyphs also have `width` and `height` attributes of their own and there was a conflict. But, it probably should have been retained for the `figure` call as aliases for `plot_width` and `plot_height`. I have added a ticket to restore these as aliases in `figure`:

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/bokeh/issues/897

In the mean time, you can pass `plot_width` and `plot_height` to `figure(...)` and it will size the plot the way you want.

If you want to clear the `plotting.py` session state, `reset_output()` was added in 0.5.1. Here is a full working script:

```
x = [0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5]
y = [0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9]
import bokeh.plotting as bplt
bplt.reset_output()
bplt.output_file('output.html')
bplt.figure(tools="wheel_zoom", plot_width=100, plot_height=300)
bplt.hold()
bplt.circle(x, y, color='red', 
   line_color='black', fill_alpha = 0.8, size = 10,
   title = 'Ternary plot', background_fill='#dddddd')
bplt.line(x=[0,0.5],y=[1,0.134])
bplt.line(x=[0.5,1],y=[0.134,1])
bplt.line(x=[1,0],y=[1,1])
bplt.show()
```